# give a prefab clones a script from another prefab in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity

I have the following :

TurretBallmanager :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretBallManager : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public GameObject BallPrefab;
public GameObject TurretPrefab;
public static TurretBallManager instance;
public int turretSpawnTime=35;
public int LastTurretTime=0;
Vector2 v;
void Start () {
    instance = this;
    v = new Vector2(TurretPrefab.transform.position.x,TurretPrefab.transform.position.y);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Time.time > LastTurretTime + turretSpawnTime) {
        GameObject T = Instantiate(TurretPrefab,v,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        //T.AddComponent<Turret>();
        v.x=T.transform.position.x+2;
    }
  }
}
```

Turret class :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Turret : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
double LastBallTime=0.0;
double LastTurretTime=0.0;
public decimal spawnballTime=1.5;
Vector2 v ;
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Time.time > LastBallTime + spawnballTime) {
        LastBallTime=Time.time;     
        Debug.Log (transform.position);
        GameObject B = Instantiate(TurretBallManager.instance.BallPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        //B.AddComponent<Ball>();
    }

  }
}
```

Ball class :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}
void OnMouseDown() {
    Object.Destroy (gameObject);
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}


void OnBecameInvisible ()
{
    Debug.Log ("destroyed");
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
}
```

I have a turret wish fire a ball every 1 sec ,the ball is a prefab wish have the Ball class ( when the ball is out of bounds or is touched it should be destroyed ) what i'm trying to do is creating a another turret every `35 sec` wish also should fire a ball every 1 sec ..
what i am facing is the fallowing problem :

1. the turret is being created after `35 sec` but it's ball are not implementing the `ball script` and they are not being destroyed
2. An overflow is occurring due to the number of balls created and the whole project is freezing

[image: As soon as the game begin]

[image: When 35 seconds ends]

[image: you can see that millions of turrets are created at the same time as soon as 35 sec ends]

- Image 1 : as soon as the game begin
- Image 2 : When 35 seconds ends
- Image 3 : you can see that millions of turrets are created at the same time as soon as 35 sec ends

The `turretballmanager` is a class given for the Maincamera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`// Update is called once per frame`

Your timer is never being reset. This means that after the soon as your spawning condition is satisfied: `if (Time.time > LastTurretTime + turretSpawnTime)`, your program will continue to spawn turrets every time `Update()` is called. You appear to have a better approach in your ball spawner.

You could update the `LastTurretTime` like so:

```
 if (Time.time > LastTurretTime + turretSpawnTime) {
        LastTurretTime = Time.time;
        GameObject T = Instantiate(TurretPrefab,v,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        //T.AddComponent<Turret>();
        v.x=T.transform.position.x+2;
    }
```

Comment: yeah i figure that out eventually :D , thank you for your reply